# SQL - must return 0 if GROUP_CONCAT value is null

Tags: sql, group-concat

I just want to not return any row if no result!
I'm so null in sql that it depresses me, please help..

I have 2 tables with 1 association table :

shop table:

| id | name | adress |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | name1 | 1 street.. |
| 2 | name2 | 2 street.. |
| 3 | name3 | 3 street.. |

activity table:

| id | title |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Distribution |
| 2 | Importation |
| 3 | Préparation |
| 4 | Production |

shop_activity association table:

| shop_id | activity_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 3 | 4 |

I found this request to concat activities:

```
    SELECT s.*, GROUP_CONCAT(a.title SEPARATOR ',') AS activities
    FROM shop s
    LEFT JOIN shop_activity sa
        ON s.id = sa.shop_id
    LEFT JOIN activity a
         ON sa.activity_id = a.id
    WHERE s.id = ?
```

and it does the job

| id | name | adress | activities |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | name3 | 3 street.. | Production, Importation |

but if s.id doesn't exist in table shop, currently I have this result:

| id | name | adress | activities |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |

but I don't want any row if all is null to return a message, currently I make a condition on id column and I know that it isn't very clean!

Comment: What is your DBMS? Generally an sql system will return no rows if WHERE condition is never true.

Comment: it's MySQL. I think it's because GROUP_CONCAT because without concat and join tables result is empty.

Comment: Sample data would help.

Comment: @Serg done, I update the question with simple data

Answer (score 0):

Try just join instead of LEFT:

```
SELECT s.*, GROUP_CONCAT(a.title SEPARATOR ',') AS activities
FROM shop s
JOIN shop_activity sa
    ON s.id = sa.shop_id
JOIN activity a
     ON sa.activity_id = a.id
WHERE s.id = ?
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found: just group by

```
SELECT s.*, GROUP_CONCAT(a.title SEPARATOR ',') AS activities
FROM shop s
LEFT JOIN shop_activity sa ON s.id = sa.shop_id
LEFT JOIN activity a ON sa.activity_id = a.id
WHERE s.id = ?
GROUP By s.id
```